# Sight distances in Savage Worlds

Tags: savage-worlds, vision-and-light

Simple question, but how is sight distance handled in Savage Worlds? I'm familiar with Pathfinder and DND where a PC has like Darkvision that works for up to 60 feet. What is the standard viewing distance in a well lit space? What about in different levels of luminosity down to total dark?

Answer (score 4):

Standard viewing distance for a well lit space is not specified anywhere in the core rules. The Dim lighting condition gives a -1 to rolls but again, no distance limit. The Dark lighting condition gives a -2 to rolls, and you cant see anything beyond 10" on a battlemat, which is 20 yards. Pitch Darkness, as the name would suggest, means you cannot see any distance at all.

Comment: Hmmm... okay. I suppose distance limitations mainly make sense when darkness comes in to play. I'll see what I can do with this. Thanks! :D

Comment: Also, if there is a question whether something can or can't be seen, just make a Notice roll with the appropriate penalties. If it would be silly for them not to see it, then don't bother making a roll.